# Is there a way to directly call a function of an object?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-2, google-swiffy

As you know, Swiffy convert everything to javascript. Therefore if my AS2 script create an object, it should be stored inside this swiffy object somewhere. And if I create a function for this object in AS2, this function should also exist as javascript thing somewhere. But the question is, where is it? I would be much more convenient if i can direct control things inside the swf converted object

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `flash.external.ExternalInterface.addCallback` to bind the function onto the Swiffy container element?

If you adds something like this in your SWF:

```
flash.external.ExternalInterface.addCallback(
    'saySomething', object, object.saySomething);
```

Then you should be able to call that from the host page like this:

```
document.getElementById('swiffycontainer').saySomething('hello');
```

Comment: I don't think this suit what i need. It's AS3 and we have to edit each fla file to add this feature.